# Problem of lack of storage space in the system storage

Tags: storage, partitions, lg, operating-system

Partitioning LG Optimus L3 E405F, i need space in system storage to download applications from google play.

My device is LG Optimus L3 E405F.

- System storage: I think 220-odd MB
- Internal Storage: 1GB

How to increase System Storage, i have access superuser (root) on my device.

Comment: First, you don't need "space in the system storage" to download apps from Playstore: `/system` is mounted read-only, and apps the user installs (normally, not via root) are not installed there but below `/data`. Second, be careful with re-partitioning unless you know exactly what you're doing; you might make future OS updates "difficult" (and OTA updates fail). I recommend you start by reading our [storage tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/storage/info) and follow up its links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to do partition of your SD card using a SD card Partition app (by partitioning, all data of SD card will be erased). Then you will have to use 'Link2sd' app to move your installed apps in the SD card (needs superuser access). By moving apps to SD card, not the whole app will be moved to SD card but about 40-50% of the app's memory will be stored in that partition of SD card.

Comment: i not need 1gb internal storage.... i need only 400mb

Comment: Ya thats the same thing. You add additional 400MB to your storage OR you free up 400MB from the pre-installed apps, the motive of both the things is same i.e. to get extra 400 MB space...